# caliburn.micro Condutor not working

Tags: c#, .net, caliburn.micro

We are using caliburn.micro for one of our projects and I'm currently having a puzzling problem:

we have the following classes:

```
ToolViewerViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive
DocViewerViewModel : Conductor<DocumentViewModel>
```

and various document-views, all with this base class:

```
DocumentViewModel : Screen
```

The `ToolViewerViewModel` is to manage multiple dock-able tool views which allow the user to control different aspects of the program.

The `DocViewerViewModel` is to show the user the data he's working on/with. It is here to present one of the many `DocumentViewModel` to the user. and is implemented as a special dock-able view which can not be closed or detached from the `ToolViewerView`. For every aspect of the data a specific `DocumentViewModel` is generated by the `DocViewerViewModel` and presented to the user.

The `DocumentViewModel` is the base class for all presentation aspects of the data. One may present the data as a table an other may present it as a chart, and so on...

We now encounter problems in terms of `OnActivate()` and `OnDeactivate()` which are not called when we expect them to be called.

First Problem:
The system is up and running; The `DocumentViewModel` is displayed in the `DocViewerViewModel` which is embedded in the `ToolViewerViewModel` along with one or two other dock-able views. The currently selected dock-able view is the `DocViewerViewModel`. When the user now selects one of the other dock-able views the `OnDeactivate()` method from the `DocumentViewModel` is being called. Which makes absolutely no sense to me. I'd expect the `DocViewerViewModel.OnDeactivate()` to be called.

Second Problem:
The system is up and running; The `DocumentViewModel` is displayed in the `DocViewerViewModel` which is embedded in the `ToolViewerViewModel` along with one or two other dock-able views. The currently selected dock-able view is the view that enables the user to change the `DocumentViewModel` presented by the `DocViewerViewModel`. When the user now selects an other `DocumentViewModel` the following code is being executed within the `DocViewerViewModel`:

```
DocViewerViewModel.DeactivateItem(oldDocumentViewModel, true);
DocViewerViewModel.ActivateItem(new DocumentViewModel());
```

I'd expect the `DocumentViewModel.OnDeactivate()` to be called upon the `DocViewerViewModel.DeactivateItem(oldDocumentViewModel, true)` call. but that never happens.

Conclusion:
The only proper working Conductor is the `ToolViewerViewModel` which is managing everything. But this behavior is not what we want or expect to happen: We'd like to have the `ToolViewerViewModel` only Conduct the dock-able views and the `DocViewerViewModel` to conduct the `DocumentViewModel`. This is important because there are two different use cases in place: One to manage multiple instances at the same time and the other where only one instance is active and used, the old instance shall be thrown away.

Hopefully anyone here can help me to get the behavior I'm looking for.

I Now have an example code for you:

```
public class ToolViewerViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    private readonly IDockManager _dockManager;
    private readonly DocViewerViewModel _docViewerViewModel;
    private readonly IList<DockableViewModel> _toolViews = new List<DockableViewModel>();

    public ToolViewerViewModel(IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory, DocViewerViewModel docViewerViewModel, IDockManager dockManager)
    {
        _dockManager = dockManager;
        _viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
        _docViewerViewModel = docViewerViewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        _dockManager.Link(this);
        _dockManager.CreateSpecialPaneFor(_docViewerViewModel);
        ActivateItem(_docViewerViewModel);

        ShowToolView<ProjectExplorerViewModel>();
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);
    }

    public void ShowToolView<T>() where T : DockableViewModel
    {
        if (!IsToolViewOpen<T>())
        {
            var viewModel = _viewModelFactory.Create<T>();
            ActivateItem(viewModel);
            RefreshMenu(typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Next class:

```
public class DocViewerViewModel : Conductor<DocumentViewModel>
{
    private readonly IViewModelFactory _viewModelFactory;

    public DocViewerViewModel(IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory)
    {
        _viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
    }

    public bool ShowInMainView<T>() where T : DocumentViewModel
    {
        return ShowInMainView(typeof(T));
    }

    private bool ShowInMainView(Type viewModelType)
    {
        var ret = false;

        // close the current view
        if (ActiveItem != null)
        {
            DeactivateItem(ActiveItem, true); //The close flag is on true since we want to remove the current instance from the memory
        }

        // check whether the current viewModel has been closed successfully
        if (ActiveItem == null)
        {
            try
            {
                var viewModel = _viewModelFactory.Create(viewModelType) as DocumentViewModel;
                if (viewModel != null)
                {
                    ActivateItem(viewModel);
                    ret = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ActivateItem(_viewModelFactory.Create<NoDataViewModel>());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ActivateItem(_viewModelFactory.Create<NoDataViewModel>());
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

and the last one:

```
public abstract class DocumentViewModel : Screen
{
    private bool _isDirty;

    protected IViewModelFactory ViewModelFactory { get; private set; }
    protected IEventAggregator EventAggregator { get; private set; }

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get
        {
            return _isDirty;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_isDirty))
            {
                return;
            }
            _isDirty = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsDirty);
        }
    }

    protected DocumentViewModel(IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        ViewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
        EventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
    {
        if (close)
        {
            if (EventAggregator != null)
            {
                EventAggregator.Unsubscribe(this);
            }
        }
        base.OnDeactivate(close);
    }

    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        if (EventAggregator != null)
        {
            EventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        }
        base.OnActivate();
    }

    public override void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
    {
        var ret = true;
        if (IsDirty && (ViewModelFactory != null))
        {
            var saveDialog = ViewModelFactory.Create<SaveDialogViewModel>();
            saveDialog.Show();
            if (saveDialog.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                ret = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (saveDialog.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Save();
                }
                else
                {
                    Discard();
                }
                IsDirty = false;
            }
        }
        callback(ret);
    }

    public abstract void Save();

    public virtual void Discard()
    {
    }
}
```

With this code the only time the `DocumentViewModel.OnDeactivate()` is being called when the user brings an other dock-able view into focus while the `DocViewerViewModel` was having the focus. This should not happen!

When the user is changing the focus between the dock-able views the  `DocumentViewModel.OnDeactivate()` should not get call. But it must get called when ever the Method `DocViewerViewModel.ShowInMainView<SomeDocumentViewModel>()` is being called. Which isn't the case currently.

Comment: Can you post an example project? It sounds to be like ToolViewerViewModel should be a Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive but it's hard to visualize the problem.

Comment: Interestingly the call DocViewerViewModel.DeactivateItem(oldDocumentViewModel, true); does call the method DocumentViewModel.CanClose(Action<bool> callback).

Comment: @BenjaminPaul: I am currently trying to reduce my code to the importend stuff so i can post is. But your suggestion is not the right solution for several reasons:

Comment: First: I tried that but the toolViews are not all active at the same time, nor would we want that.

Comment: Second: the dockManager could not handle it that way

Comment: third: this would also mean that all our DocumentViewModels would all be active at once even if they should get removed by the GC...

Comment: But thank you, It was definitely worth a try...

Comment: You will have more luck with an example of your project, unfortunately it's very hard to visualize what you are trying to achieve from the description in your post.

Comment: By now I would have an example but the site refuses to let me post it

Comment: @BenjaminPaul: Thank you for your help. I hope my example is what you had in mind...

Comment: Can we see one of the classes which derive from `DocumentViewModel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our Solution for that Problem is to remove the use `Screen` as BaseClass for `DocViewerViewModel` an implement the Conductor Logic our self.

Comment: I think it's a bit unfair to downgrade an answer I've given to a question that has not been answered so far. After all I took the time and told you my work around. Other unanswered questions just stay there for ever without the attention of the questioner...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with the way your code is written. Since you are using MVVM, I suggest you design a test case like I've provided [here](https://gist.github.com/teyc/9560189).

And here's a snippet of the test case

```
// TestHarness.cs

[TestMethod]
public void CheckDeactivation()
{
    // We'd like to have the ToolViewerViewModel only Conduct the dock-able views 
    // and the DocViewerViewModel to conduct the DocumentViewModel.

    IViewModelFactory factory = new ViewModelFactory();
    DocViewerViewModel docViewer = new DocViewerViewModel(factory);
    IDockManager dockManager = null;

    var toolViewer = new ToolViewerViewModel(factory, docViewer, dockManager);
    var mockToolView = new UserControl();           
    (toolViewer as IViewAware).AttachView(mockToolView);

    DocumentViewModel docView1 = new NoDataViewModel();
    DocumentViewModel docView2 = new NoDataViewModel();
    docViewer.ActivateItem(docView1);
    docViewer.ActivateItem(docView2);

    Assert.AreEqual(0, docViewer.CountDeactivated());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem as you, and ended up using PropertyChangedBase instead of Screen and got the problem to disappear.
Later, after reading the docs on Screens and Conductors [here](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition), I realized that I wasn't activating the conductor itself further up in the view hierarchy!

So have a look at wherever you use your ToolViewerViewModel, and make sure you activate that instance!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your Test. Even thought it is really nice code it tests the wrong code part. Your code simply tests whether the Method `ActivateItem()` or `DeactivateItem()` is being called:

```
public override void ActivateItem(DocumentViewModel item)
{
    _countActivated++;
    base.ActivateItem(item);
}

public override void DeactivateItem(DocumentViewModel item, bool close)
{
     _countDeactivated++;
     base.DeactivateItem(item, close);
}
```

But since these Methods are being called explicitly we don't need to test for that...

The real Problem is that the Conductor is not calling the `OnActivate()` or `OnDeactivate()` on the `DocumentViewModel` class. To enhance your test I used the following code:

```
public class DummyViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _registredCreators = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>();

    public T Create<T>() where T : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        return Create(typeof(T)) as T;
    }

    public object Create(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (_registredCreators.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return _registredCreators[type]();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void Release(object instance)
    {
    }

    public void RegisterCreatorFor<T>(Func<T> creatorFunction)
    {
        _registredCreators.Add(typeof(T), () => creatorFunction());
    }
}
```

As concrete `DocumentViewModel` implementation I made:

```
public class NoDataViewModel : DocumentViewModel
{
    public NoDataViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
        IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory)
        : base(viewModelFactory, eventAggregator, )
    {
    }

    public override void Save()
    {
        // nothing to do
    }

    public override void Reload()
    {
        // nothing to do
    }
}

public class NoDataViewModelMock : NoDataViewModel
{
    private static int activationCounterForTesting = 0;
    private static int deactivationCounterForTesting = 0;

    public static int ActivationCounterForTesting
    {
        get
        {
            return activationCounterForTesting;
        }
    }

    public static int DeactivationCounterForTesting
    {
        get
        {
            return deactivationCounterForTesting;
        }
    }

    public NoDataViewModelMock()
        : base(null, null)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        activationCounterForTesting++;
        base.OnActivate();
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
    {
        deactivationCounterForTesting++;
        base.OnDeactivate(close);
    }
}
```

And I changed your Testmethod to this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckDeactivation()
{
    var viewModelFactory = new DummyViewModelFactory();

    viewModelFactory.RegisterCreatorFor<NoDataViewModel>(() => new NoDataViewModelMock());

    var docViewer = new DocViewerViewModel(viewModelFactory);
    IDockManager dockManager = null;

    var toolViewer = new ToolViewerViewModel(viewModelFactory, docViewer, dockManager);
    var mockToolView = new UserControl();
    (toolViewer as IViewAware).AttachView(mockToolView);

    docViewerViewModel.ShowInMainView<NoDataViewModel>();
    docViewerViewModel.ShowInMainView<NoDataViewModel>();
    docViewerViewModel.ShowInMainView<NoDataViewModel>();

    Assert.AreEqual(3, NoDataViewModelMock.ActivationCounterForTesting);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, NoDataViewModelMock.DeactivationCounterForTesting);
}
```

Then you'll see that the `OnActivate()` and `OnDeactivate()` methods are never been called.

With a little more advanced test you'd also see that they are being called but from the `ToolViewerViewModel` directly. I'd like to know why and how I can change this behavior to fit my needs:

- The `DocumentViewModel.OnActivate()` method should get called when the `DocViewerViewModel.ShowInMainView<T>()` method gets called.
- The `DocumentViewModel.OnDeactivate()` method should get called on the old `DocumentViewModel` when a new one is being shown by calling the `DocViewerViewModel.ShowInMainView<T>()`